# Attempt to present UINavController on SettingsView whose view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, hierarchy, viewcontroller, mvp

When I select the log out button it doesn't transition to the main menu as I get this error: **Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

The button does in fact work as the user is logged out, I am just unable to switch view controller due to the above error.

Not sure what to do. I have read about some other people having similar problems but they all seem to be performing segues manually coded whereas I am not.

This is my current storyboard setup: [image]

Also not sure if related but a duplicate of the settings button appears at the bottom of the first view controller when running the app, despite not being there as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: you have two nested navigation controllers???

Comment: it looks like you pushed a navigation controller to another navController

Comment: @Banto25 I had to because the sign up and login buttons couldn't use their segues. The two Navs aren't directly linked anyway.